# Чем отличается сценарий от модуля?

Tags: python-3.x

Правильно ли я понимаю, что сценарий и модуль в python - суть одно и то же? Или различия всё же есть? Если есть, то подскажите в чём именно.

Comment: Да, это одно и то же. В `Python` каждый сценарий — модуль.

Comment: Модульностью. Сферический сценарий в вакууме невозможно переиспользовать.